# trouble with mathematical induction question

Tags: proof-writing, induction

does anyone have any ideas on this proof. I have been stuck on it for hours now. Thanks for the help in advance [Image of Question is in this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NsV1.png)

> Prove that for all natural numbers $\geq 1$:
>
> $$\frac {1}{\sqrt1} +\frac {1}{\sqrt2}+\frac {1}{\sqrt3}+.....+\frac {1}{\sqrt n} \leq 2 \sqrt n $$

Comment: What have you tried? What part of it are you stuck on? We cannot help you if you provide no particular information.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: I get stuck on the part where I assume its true for n = x, then use that to try and prove its true for n = x+1. When I do this I get the inequality 2x^0.5(x+1)^0.5 < 2x +1. If I can prove this I think I should be done, but I am unable to prove this inequality.

Answer (score 1):

**Basis**
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}}<2\sqrt{1}$$

**Induction hypothesis**
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}<2\sqrt{n}$$

**Inductive step**
To Show: $$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}<2\sqrt{n+1}$$

$$LHS=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}$$
$$<2\sqrt{n}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}$$
$$=2\sqrt{n+1}-(2\sqrt{n+1}-2\sqrt{n}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}})$$
$$=2\sqrt{n+1}-(\frac{2}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}})$$
$$<2\sqrt{n+1}=RHS$$

Answer (score 0):

If a non-inductive proof is acceptable, note that for any decreasing function $f(x)$,
$$\sum_{x=1}^n f(x) \le \int_0^n f(x) \;dx $$
(If you have trouble seeing this, it might help to make a sketch.)

Taking $f(x) = x^{-1/2}$, we have
$$\sum_{x=1}^n x^{-1/2} \le \int_0^n x^{-1/2} \; dx = 2 n ^{1/2}$$